# What about this sentence does not make sense?

Tags: semantics, grammar

From the16types.info forum, signature of user exsomnis:

> Either serve me now with comfortable deeds or disappear.

What exactly is incorrect with the adjective "comfortable" modifying the noun "deeds"? It sounds off.

Comment: What do you think it means? What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: Only a sentient being can be *comfortable* in the sense "to feel at ease". Perhaps *comforting* was what was intended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Book of Common Prayer describes some sayings of Jesus as [comfortable words](https://omeka.drew.edu/exhibits/show/comfortablewords/intro), but, as paragraph 6 explains, it doesn't mean *comfortable* in the modern sense. *To comfort* originally referred to giving strength and support rather than relieving distress or giving physical ease.

So, in modern English, *comfortable* is not an appropriate word to describe deeds.

Answer (score 2):

OED

**Comfortable** adjective

> **I.1.a. Strengthening or supporting (morally or spiritually); encouraging, inspiriting, reassuring, cheering.** Obsolete or archaic.
>
> c1460 (?c1400) His wordis been so comfortabill. *Tale of Beryn
> Prologue l. 721*
>
> 1869 He spake and cheer'd his Table Round With large divine and
> comfortable words. *Lord Tennyson, Coming of Arthur 267*

So, in answer to the question

> What exactly is incorrect with the adjective "comfortable" modifying the noun "deeds"?

It is obsolete rather than incorrect in this sense.